# Hola buenas tardes me podrian orientar... Como puedo subir mi proyecto node y de react a un servidor web?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Es un servidor web con sistema operativo windows, donde deberia colocar el proyecto para que  otros usuario puedan ingresar por la web desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

tienes que instalar node en ese servidor, e iisnode: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases

y luego en la carpeta archivos del programa o program files x84 -> iisnode\wwww\ creas la carpeta para el proyecto y pegas el contenido, luego lo arrancas como lo haces en local, vas al firewall y creas una nueva entrada, para poder activar el puerto en el que corre la web, para hacer que se pueda acceder desde cualquier sitio, creo que tienes que usar algo como el pfsense o algo por el estilo pero ahí ya no lo sé, lo que te aconsejaría si tienes bastante prisa, es usar algo como heroku para lanzar la web, que puedes subir un número de webs de forma gratuita: https://portalmybot.com/guia/heroku/inicio, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Ahora se habla mucho del tema de seguridad, y pues hay que recordar que publicar un sitio web implica cosas como mantenimiento, protección y monitoreo. No es algo que se debería tomar como una acción individual, más bien como un proceso continuo, así que si no tienes experiencia en esos temas te recomiendo que busques en internet algún curso aunque sea en youtube para familiarizarte.

En el sitio oficial de Microsoft encontré [este artículo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-sitio-web-con-iis-y-windows-7-c441e1ad-d8af-46ad-13d2-cd2d7d687c30) que debería ayudarte. El proceso es bastante largo como para copiarlo aquí pero asegúrate que tengas IIS instalado. Si por el contrario estás usando otro servidor web sería bueno que lo mencionaras, al igual que cualquier error o síntoma que estés viendo.

Saludos